# Quicken 98 deluxe financial calendar

Tags: quicken

I run this SW since the nineties, from Windows 3.1 to 98, XP, 7 and now 10.

Somewhere I found the solution to the "your backup disk is aout of space" message.

But now one of the most convenients features (for me) is gone.

In the financial calendar, if I aim the mouse at the histogram of a day it doesn't show the balance amount any more.

Anybody got this problem AND THE SOLUTION  ?

Thank you in advance and best regards.

Aldo

Comment: I really doubt you're going to find anyone else who has kept a piece of 22 year-old software running til now. It's not like there isn't a modern version.

Comment: Perhaps get yourself a Virtual Machine (VM) of an OS it was stable on (eg 98,XP,7) and you can run it forever without fear of further issues. PS: good job keeping it going this long... I love me some legacy software that just keeps going. Sure beats paying for a frekken subacription sercice these days.